# TinyButStrong (OpenTBS) add row to table in doc or odt file

Tags: php, opentbs

I'm using TinyButStrong with OpenTBS plugin and I need to display a table with a products list. My problem is that it only displays the first product.

In one of the cells I defined block=tbs:row but it's not creating a row for each element in my array of products.

```
[PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME;block=tbs:row]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TBS tag definition is correct, but the tag may have invisible splits in the inner XML because of spelling-grammar, formatting splits, or change tracks.

In order to avoid this, you can use the OpenTBS add-in for Ms Word (if your template is DOCX), or simply do:

1. select the TBS tag
2. cut the TBS tag
3. use « paste without formatting » at the same place

Comment: That was the problem. I spotted them by enabling the debug.
$TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_DEBUG_XML_CURRENT, true);
$TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_DEBUG_INFO, true); 
$TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_DEBUG_XML_SHOW);